# Silverlight does not include assemblies with names ending with ".Resources" in the Application manifest

Tags: silverlight, manifest

I shifted my Silverlight 5 application resources from the application to a separate assembly which I named X.Y.Resources.

After my application stopped working I noticed that the X.Y.Resources assembly was not included in the Application Manifest and therefore missing from the XAP file.

It appears that any assembly name ending with ".Resources" is not included in the application manifest and hence not included in the XAP file.

This results in a FileNotFoundException when any reference is made to members of the missing assembly.

On reflection it was probably a bad idea to end the assembly name .Resources and the problem was easily resolved by changing that to .AppResources.

Does anybody know why this problem occurs or is it an obscure VS2012/Silverlight bug?

Comment: The same in Windows Phone 8 runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I found this bug in wpf also (from vs2008 to vs2012) and only manage to fix it by changing the name of the project to one that not ended in resources...